# Free software to screen shot webpages and reveal content inside drop down list or sub menu

Tags: web-browser, screenshot

Sometime, we encounter a webpage that contain either many drop down list such as the one below

[image: menu]

or menu that have sub menu in them

[image: screenshot]

So, is there a special web browser or tools that allow one to screen shot the webpage (and at the same time reveal the content inside the drop down list or sub menu) into one or many image file(s) and have the ability to control the quality of the image (such as the percentage of compression for JPG format)?

Answer (score 1):

Well, years ago I searched for the optimal screen capture tool and settled on [SandStone Screen Capture](http://www.faststone.org/).

It has gone commercial, but You can download the last freeware version [HERE](http://www.portablefreeware.com/download.php?id=775)

I have just checked (using the free version, and, yes, it can capture drop down menus and combo boxes)
[image]

Btw, I recommend that change the settings to delay a few seconds before taking the snapshot to give you time to select the menu or combo box.

Btw, teh program has **many** more great features, but I only mention what you asked for.